# Listing books by priority

Tags: c#, performance, sorting

```
#region GetBookListByPriority
private static List<BCBook> GetBookListByPriority(List<BCBook> listBcBook)
{
    List<BCBook> newList = new List<BCBook>();
    try
    {
        List<BCBook> listNonPriorityBcBooks = new List<BCBook>();
        List<BCBook> listPriorityBcBooks = new List<BCBook>();

        foreach (BCBook bcBook in listBcBook)
        {
            BookHistoryDto historyDto = new BookHistoryFacade().FindHistoryByBookIdByPriority(bcBook.id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            if (historyDto != null && historyDto.HistoryId > 0)
            {
                bcBook.Priority = historyDto.Priority;
                listPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
            }
            else
            {
                listNonPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        int prio = 0;
        foreach (BCBook bcBook in listNonPriorityBcBooks)
        {
            for (int j = count + 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                List<BCBook> listBook = new List<BCBook>();
                listBook = ListBookPriority(listPriorityBcBooks, j, newList);
                count++;
                if (listBook.Count() > 0)
                {
                    prio++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                foreach (BCBook bc in listBook)
                {
                    newList.Add(bc);
                }
            }
            newList.Add(bcBook);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger.WriteErrorToLog(ex);
    }

    return newList;
}
#endregion

#region ListBookPriority
private static List<BCBook> ListBookPriority(List<BCBook> list, int priority, List<BCBook> newList)
{

    List<BCBook> listBook = new List<BCBook>();
    try
    {
        foreach (BCBook vid in list)
        {
            if (!IsExists(newList, vid.id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
            {
                if (vid.Priority == priority)
                {
                    listBook.Add(vid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger.WriteErrorToLog(ex);
    }
    return listBook;
} 
#endregion
```

Comment: You have several loops there. Which one is "*this loop*?"

Comment: Step 1 is to add comments to your code explaining the intent.  There is probably a better approach to what you are trying to do. Keeping track of count and prior seem odd since you never use either one.

Answer (score 2):

I would get rid of `foreach` and use `for`. I have found (and read about) a huge performance difference between the 2 (***EDIT***, but not always, see below).

**Example (untested code):**

```
int c  = listBcBook.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    BCBook bcBook = listBcBook[i];

    BookHistoryDto historyDto = new BookHistoryFacade().FindHistoryByBookIdByPriority(bcBook.id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    if (historyDto != null && historyDto.HistoryId > 0)
    {
        bcBook.Priority = historyDto.Priority;
        listPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
    }
    else
    {
        listNonPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just read that the performance difference isn't always there because in some cases, the compiler will optimize your `foreach` loops into `for` loops. Here is a good read over on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c.

In your case, because you're using a `List`, directly using `for` should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have time at the moment to look through the code at the moment (and due to the lack of comments) I can't give a broad answer but I can already note two things.

Initialize your facade outside of the for loop.

```
BookHistoryFacade() facade = new BookHistoryFacade();
foreach (BCBook bcBook in listBcBook)
{
    BookHistoryDto historyDto =
       facade.FindHistoryByBookIdByPriority(bcBook.id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    ...
}
```

Use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) for your queries, which will also allow you to easily attempt [Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx). This would give you the opportunity to use several cores for your query ... aka as increased speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace two foreach loops in GetBookListByPriority where you're adding the whole sublist to a new list with these:

```
newList.AddRange(listBook);
newList.AddRange(listNonPriorityBcBooks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty unclear what the code does/needs to do. But I've tried to cut down on some of the code so try this (obviously untested) and see if its faster and does the same thing :)

```
    private static List<BCBook> GetBookListByPriority(List<BCBook> listBcBook)
    {
        List<BCBook> newList = new List<BCBook>();
        try
        {
            List<BCBook> listNonPriorityBcBooks = new List<BCBook>();
            List<BCBook> listPriorityBcBooks = new List<BCBook>();
            // move the variable historyDto outside the for loop so you create the object less.
            BookHistoryDto historyDto;
            foreach (BCBook bcBook in listBcBook)
            {
                historyDto = new BookHistoryFacade().FindHistoryByBookIdByPriority(bcBook.id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
                if (historyDto != null && historyDto.HistoryId > 0)
                {
                    bcBook.Priority = historyDto.Priority;
                    listPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
                }
                else
                {
                    listNonPriorityBcBooks.Add(bcBook);
                }
            }

            int count = 1; 
            foreach (BCBook bcBook in listNonPriorityBcBooks)
            {
                // move the variable listBook outside the for loop so you create the object less.
                List<BCBook> listBook;
                // if you are only having a maximum of 5 then there is no need to create an extra variable, use the existing count
                for (count; count <= 5; count++)
                {
                    listBook = ListBookPriority(listPriorityBcBooks, count, newList);
                    // Count() is slower than Count, note the difference in the removal of the brackets
                    if (listBook.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Only if the count is greater than 0 do we want to begin to enumerate the collection
                        foreach (BCBook bc in listBook)
                        {
                            newList.Add(bc);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                newList.Add(bcBook);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.WriteErrorToLog(ex);
        }

        return newList;
    }
```

If you could comment your original code you would get a better response i'm sure

Answer (score 0):

You are not optimizing anything with that:

```
int count = 1; 
// Some code here
for (count; count <= 5; count++)
{
```

This is equal in speed, but inferior in style to:

```
// Some code here
for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
{
```

Avoid these "micro-optimizations". Even if done right, it is often the case that you will have much better things to improve.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use LINQ as Steven suggests, have you considered a SortedList?  Just implement the IComparable interface on the priority object if it doesn't already.